# List Remove Item OffSet

Tags: visualforce, list, selectlist

Below I select all accounts and I remove accounts with the lastactivitydate <60 days. Now I have a problem with the offset size, because I show on each page 12 records, but If a record is removed, the page shows only 11 records. 
How can I solve this problem?

```
TotalRecs = 0;
OffsetSize = 0;
LimitSize = 12;

 List <Account> Acc = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Name, BillingCity, NumberOfEmployees, Owner.Name, LastActivityDate FROM Account ORDER BY Name limit ' + LimitSize + ' offset ' + OffSetSize];

   FOR(Integer j = 0; j < Acc.size(); j++) {
            IF(((today.getTime() - Acc.get(j).LastActivityDate.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24)) <60){
                Acc.remove(j);                              
            } 
        }
RETURN Acc;
```

**EDIT 01.07.2015**

```
Public List <Account> getAccList2() {
String SearchStringConvert = '%' + SearchString + '%';
Boolean isEmptySearch = String.isEmpty(SearchString);
Boolean isEmptyStatus = String.isEmpty(SelectedStatus);
Boolean isEmptyUser = String.isEmpty(SelectedUserId);
Boolean isEmptyStand = String.isEmpty(SelectedStand);    

IF (isEmptySearch && isEmptyStatus && isEmptyUser && isEmptyStand) {
    ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, 'Please enter value'));
RETURN NULL;
}

String SelectClause = 'SELECT Id, OwnerId, Name, BillingCity, NumberOfEmployees, Owner.Name, (SELECT LastModifiedDate FROM Opportunities ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC Limit 1) FROM Account';
String LimitClause = ' ORDER BY Name limit ' + LimitSize + ' offset ' + OffSetSize;    
String CountSelectClause = 'SELECT Count() FROM Account';
String CountLimitClause = ' LIMIT 2000';

List <String> WhereClauses = new List <String>();

IF (!isEmptyStand) {
    IF (SelectedStand == 'GREEN') {
        WhereClauses.Add('Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:60)');
    } 
    ELSE IF (SelectedStand == 'YELLOW') {
        WhereClauses.Add('Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:60 AND LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:180)');
    }
    ELSE IF (SelectedStand == 'RED') {
        WhereClauses.Add('Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:180)');
    }  
    ELSE IF (SelectedStand == 'LEER') {
        WhereClauses.Add('Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity)');
    }          
}      

IF (!isEmptySearch) {
    WhereClauses.Add('Name LIKE \'' + SearchStringConvert + '\'');
}
IF (!isEmptyStatus) {
    WhereClauses.Add('Status__c = \'' + SelectedStatus + '\'');
}
IF (!isEmptyUser) {
    WhereClauses.Add('OwnerId = \'' + SelectedUserId + '\'');
}
String WhereClause = ' WHERE ' + String.join(WhereClauses, ' AND ');

String SQL = SelectClause + WhereClause + LimitClause;
String SQLCount = CountSelectClause + WhereClause + CountLimitClause;  

List <Account> Acc = Database.query(SQL);
TotalRecs = Database.CountQuery(SQLCount);

dateTime heute = dateTime.now();        

    FOR(Integer j = Acc.Size() - 1; j >=0; j--) {    
        IF (SelectedStand == 'YELLOW') {
            IF(((heute.getTime() - Acc.get(j).Opportunities[0].LastModifiedDate.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24)) <60){
                Acc.remove(j);                  
                TotalRecs--;                
            } 
        }
        ELSE IF (SelectedStand == 'RED') {
            IF(((heute.getTime() - Acc.get(j).Opportunities[0].LastModifiedDate.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24)) <180){
                Acc.remove(j);                 
                TotalRecs--;            
            } 
        }  
        }

RETURN Acc;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just increment backwards through the list.

```
for(Integer j = Acc.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if(Acc[j].LastActivityDate.date().daysBetween(Date.today()) < 60){
        Acc.remove(j);                              
    } 
}
```

However you can just do this in your `SOQL` without any post-processing.

```
List <Account> Acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE LastActivityDate < LAST_N_DAYS:60];
```

**Edit**

As for your updated filters, you can still accomplish what you want via `SOQL`. Merge in the following `WHERE` clauses to the appropriate evaluation section:

```
if (selectedStand == 'YELLOW')
{
    // some logic is already here
    whereClauses.add('LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:60');
}
else if (selectedStand == 'RED')
{
    // some logic is already here
    whereClauses.add('LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:180');
}
```

Comment: You can also get the days between two dates with Date.daysBetween, which is slightly less silly than doing four multiplications and a division (and uses less CPU time), but, like you say, prefer filtering when possible.

Comment: Yeah I didn't even look very hard at that part of the evaluation. You're right though, if he goes that route it should be optimized.

Comment: `for(Integer j = Acc.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--)` surely.

Comment: @KeithC So right.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but the problem is not solved. This code was a example for my problem. I added to the mainpost my whole code.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more. The LastActivityDate was an example. The real code is what I posted this morning.

Comment: Please help me. I tried a lot, but nothing helps.

Comment: Nobody can help? Please take a look. Thanks :-)

Comment: @peXeq It's really hard when you keep changing your question. If you are just using `lastModifiedDate` instead of `LastActivityDate`, just change the query string to reflect that.